# What's wrong with this (gibbs) code?

Tags: r

I'm trying to run this code with R, but it gives me error:

```
rm(list = ls())
gibbs <- function (n, k, y0, m, alpha, beta){
  z <- array (0,n)
  for (i in 1 : n) {
    x <- array (0,k)
    y <- array (0, k+1)
    y[1] <- y0
    for (j in 1 : k) {
      x[j] <- rbinom (1, m, y[j])
      y[j+1] <- rbeta (1, x[j]+alpha, m-x[j]beta)
    }
    z[i]=x[k]
  }
  print (mean(z))
  print (var(z))
}

gibbs(1000, 50, 0.5, 3, 8.5, 4.5)
```

What exactly is wrong with it? here's the error it gives:

```
 source("E:\\Program Files\\R\\test.R")
Error in source("E:\\Program Files\\R\\test.R") : 
  E:\Program Files\R\test.R:11:39: unexpected symbol
10: x[j] <- rbinom (1, m, y[j])
11: y[j+1] <- rbeta (1, x[j]+alpha, m-x[j]beta
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: There is a `+` missing (or another mathematical operator): `y[j+1] <- rbeta (1, x[j]+alpha, m-x[j]beta)`

Comment: Hiya sgibb. You're right! seems like it should be +beta. let me check the code again.

Comment: `x[j]beta` must be `x[j]+beta`

Comment: The result is this now:

> source("E:\\Program Files\\R\\test.R")
[1] 1.958
[1] 0.801037
> 

Is this right? don't know why but it just doesn't feel right?

Answer (score 1):

R does not know what operation you want between `x[j]` and `beta` in this expression `m-x[j]beta`. If you want to multiply, put a `*` there. If you want to add, put a `+` there.

It expected an operator there, so the `b` that starts `beta` is Unexpected.

Comment: Thank you. Do you think the 1.958 and 0.801037 that it gives as the result are correct?

Comment: @user3086511, That is a math question, and an application-specific question, so I unfortunately cannot answer that. I can tell you that your program will do exactly what you ask it to, but whether you are asking it to do the right thing, I cannot fathom because that would require mind-reading. :P